# Change font size on actual Spinner button object

Tags: android, text, size, spinner

I know it is possible to change the font size of the Spinner menu that pops up when the button is clicked, and I know it is possible to change the font size of an ordinary button - but I can't seem to find anything on changing the **size of the text in the actual spinner button itself**. Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the generic layout from simple_spinner_item.xml, I've added a `textSize` attribute at the bottom, let's save it as spinner_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:textSize="36sp" />
```

And you use it just like any other layout in an adapter:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I've seen this type of solution all over stackoverflow and correct me if I'm wrong - but won't this only change the text inside the pop-up spinner menu and not on the spinner button itself?

Comment: Try it. You will see this changes the size of the text in the one-line, closed spinner. (The dropdown resource affects the pop-up menu.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "text in the actual spinner button itself", except what *you* put there. *You* determined the layout that appears in the `Spinner`, in both the closed and open states, by how you set up your `SpinnerAdapter` (e.g., via layout files supplied to the constructor and to `setDropDownViewResource()`). If you want to change anything about those layouts, you need to change your layout resources or change your `SpinnerAdapter`.